# Populate cell with value from 4 possible cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I want to populate one cell based on the text value of one cell out of 4 possible choices. The other four cells will not have any values. Only one of the 4 will have a value I want to populate in the destination cell. How do I set up a formula to look in multiple cells, but only transfer the value from the cell with a value, ignoring the other 3 empty cells?

The cell with a value will change, and again, the other four cells will not have a value.

The 4 possible cells is a currency ($0.00) and the destination cell should result as currency as well.

Comment: is only one of the four will ever contain a value can you not just SUM them? that way you're end cell will always contain the same value as the populated one...

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this is what you want.

Sample data in C2:C5. Formatted as Currency $ 2 decimals.

Output in E2. Formatted as Currency $ 2 decimals.

Formula in E2

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C2:C5,MAX(IF(C2:C5="",-1,ROW(C2:C5)-ROW(C1)))),"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ <kbd>ENTER</kbd> from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula. The formula will automatically enclose in Curly Braces. This step is required.

[image]

Note - If you populate more than one cell in the range, the higher Indexed cell will be returned.

Subtracting ROW value of previous cell is required `-ROW(C1)` in this example, if the range does not start at ROW 1